# Loading a file using sqlloader

Tags: sql-loader

I was trying to insert a JSON file into a table which has only one column varchar2(4000) using sql loader. After I load I see the file text is loaded in multiple rows instead of one row , but I want them in one row , the whole file in one column and one row. Not sure why this is happening , is there a option to tell in the control file? here is my control file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'c:\json\sample-order.json'
  INTO TABLE at_jsondocs
  FIELDS  
   ( jsontext CHAR(4000) )
```

Answer (score 0):

See Alex Poole's explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684143/2543416), but the column in your table should be a CLOB, and you need to structure your control file like this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE at_jsondocs
(
  x FILLER CHAR(1),
  jsontext LOBFILE(CONSTANT "c:\json\sample-order.json") TERMINATED BY EOF
)
BEGINDATA
0
```